# ruby uninitialized constant JiraWebeeh4r (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

#### file jira_webeeh4r.rb

```
module JiraWebeeh4r
class MyWebeeh
...
do_get()
...
end
```

#### file test.rb

```
include JiraWebeeh4r
class Test
m = JiraWebeeh4r::MyWebeeh.new
m.do_get()
end
```

Then the wrong is as the title said.

Do anyone have some suggestion?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I suggest:

```
require './jira_webeeh4r'
```

Instead of the `include`.

Comment: When i use require 'jira_webeeh4r' to replace include. The error is: c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom require.rb:31 in `gem_original_require`:no such file to load -- jira_webeeh4r (LoadError) from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site ruby/1.8/rubygems/custem require.rb:31: in `require` from app/models/test.rb: 5

Comment: Oh, right, `require` will search *only* the load path, so you need to say './require' to see something local.

Comment: sorry, i could understand what you said about searching only the load path, but i couldn't know what is './require' meaning? Could you give me an example? thanks.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I *was* kind of confusing there. But I've updated my response above, changing it to suggest: `require './jira_webeeh4r'`

Comment: Oh, I know. thanks. I should use require which is as the java's class, but i couldn't set the class path, so, when i run, it's wroing.